# KendoGrid JavaScript runtime error: Invalid template

Tags: javascript, sql, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Trying to figure out the Kendo world and having an issue with a grid set to a json array datasource.

```
Error is "JavaScript runtime error: Invalid template: <tr
data-uid="#=data.uid#" role='row'><td  role='gridcell'>#=data.Account
Num==null?'':data.Account Num#</td>...".
```

I notice that in this error I see nulls, wondering if that means the data didn't bind?

I am seeing the column headers however, just not any rows. I must mention as well, I don't have any ID fields in my data as I'm using a temp table from a SQL view.

```
function populateGrid(search) {
    $("#grdAttributes").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://127.0.0.2:6080/arcgis/rest/services/WW/WW2/MapServer/exts/RestSOE/Search%20Query?columnName=" + search.columnName + "&operand=" + search.operand + "&searchVal=" + search.searchVal + "&f=",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'GET'
                }
            },
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        scrollable: true,
        height: 150

    });
    $("#grdAttributes").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view()
};
```

If I continue through the error in VS2012 I do see the column headers in the grid. Just no row data. (sample JSON below:)

```
 -[{
     -"Address": "PO BOX 20",
     -"City": "HAVENWOOD",
     -"Location": "",
     -"Name 1": "UNIVERSITY",
     -"Name 2": "",
     -"Street": "NEY AVE",
     -"Street Num": "16",
     -"Legacy ROD Num": null - "Repeat Client": "Y" -
 }, ...
```

Here is start of the error:

```
`Unhandled exception at line 11, column 6788 in
http://--------:51392/WW/js/kendo.web.min.js 0x800a139e - JavaScript
runtime error: Invalid template:'<tr data-uid="#=data.uid#"
role='row'><td  role='gridcell'>#=data.Account
Num==null?'':data.Account Num#</td><td 
role='gridcell'>#=data.address==null?'':data.address#</td><td 
role='gridcell'>#=data.Arb Location==null?'':data.Location#</td><td 
role='gridcell'>#=data.WNum==null?'':data.Num#</td><td`
```

Hopefully that's enough info to get some feedback. [banging my head].  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to tell completely, but it looks like the generated template is having problems because you have spaces in your data field names, for example:

'Account Num', and in the template it is trying to access "data.Account Num" which of course, will not work.

Set your data to have no spaces to begin with to see if that actually is the problem.
If it is the problem, another solution (if you wanted to keep the spaces) would be to manually enter the columns instead of letting it auto-generate it.

... To deal with spaces:

First set your datasource scheme up with fields like:

```
schema: {
    data: "Data",
    model: {
        fields: {
            "Name": { type: "string" },
            "Account Num": { type: "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

Then for your columns, define them with template like so:

```
columns: [
   {
      field: "Name",
      title: "Name",
      template: "#=data['Name']==null?'':data['Name']#"
   },
   {
      field: "Account Num",
      title: "Account Num",
      template: "#=data['Account Num']==null?'':data['Account Num']#"
   }
]
```

What you originally had was kendo trying to generate the template itself, but it was trying to access

```
data.Account Num
```

which of course wouldn't work in javascript, so instead, you can manually define the template of each column to instead access

```
data['Account Num']
```

which will work properly and hopefully get the result you are looking for.

Comment: I won't be able to check until tomorrow but thanks. Would the spaces still allow for the column names to display in the grid and just not the rows?

Comment: Yes, because it'll only crash when it tries to read that data, since that's when the template is used, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok gives me some hope. I've got to show some data in the gridview very soon then tackle connecting a treeview next. I was in SQL2008 today adding some LTRIM(RTRIM()) functions to the view we are using. Seems that there is some push back when I questioned a couple weeks ago why there were spaces in their table column names... so they are still there. Hoping this is the issue and I can fix it quick. Fingers crossed, I'll check it first thing tomorrow with a bunch of caffeine and let you know, thanks.

Comment: There are ways you can use to get it to show fields with spaces in it, if changing the data sent to the grid is a not an option

Comment: So my wife just laughed as I did a victory dance out of my office! I manually added a couple of columns and data showed up! Big thanks! I have to now pivot the data then wire up the treeview. So any suggestions or hints you have towards them will be well received. Thanks again.

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this. Check your data! here is the column def for showing "State", { field: "state", title: "State", width: "100px" }. This is what is in SQL, LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.ACCOUNTREC.state)) as [State], and it fails to load. However, if you use { field: "State", title: "State", width: "100px" } it loads fine.

Comment: I am interested in hearing ideas about not making database changes and showing names with spaces as well. thanks

Comment: Edited post to add somethign that should work for data with spaces, note: UNTESTED

Comment: Your template property did the trick, thanks! For some reason I'm getting a massive amount of records returning on my query. I'm going to look at it and see what's going on.

Comment: I can pose this in another question, but have you pivoted a KendoGrid before? Was asked to display this differently and I think that would do the trick. I know in sql it's: SELECT *
FROM   
 ( SELECT PId,JoinID
   FROM YourTable
  ) AS T1
PIVOT (COUNT(JoinID) FOR PId IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS T2

Comment: Only thing, this broke my treeview. Looking at how to add the template. As 'Name 1' is breaking it.